# Using existing objects as input in a mutation

Tags: asp.net, graphql, hotchocolate

I am building a graphql API using HotChocolate on ASP.NET.

I have two types, `role` as well as `permission`. `permission` consists of an id, a name and a description. `role` is almost the same, but it contains a list of `permission`'s.
I have already figured out how to create a `permission` together with a `role`.
Now I need to create a `role` without creating another `permission`, instead using an already existing `permission` in the list of `permission`'s attribute of the new `role`. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Surely there must be a way to do that without creating a whole new mutation for this, right?

Answer (score 0):

I would just create another mutation for it.

It is best practice to have very specific mutations. Checkout the [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations) as a reference.